# After adding 500 ContentNote objects to one Account by one user, nobody can add any more ContentNote records

Tags: limits, contentnote

We are developing a ContentNote integration piece.

As a `System Administrator` of a `Partner Developer` org (note: NOT the usual Dev org, although i don't know if this matters, the PD has higher limits on storage, api calls and users), i added `500` ContentNote objects using `Execute Anonymous Apex` from developer console by running the following snippet a couple of times:

```
List<ContentNote> notes = new List<ContentNote>();
List<ContentDocumentLink> l = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
for (Integer i = 200; i < 500; i++) {
    ContentNote cn = new ContentNote(Title='test ' + i, Content=Blob.valueOf('banana'));
    notes.add(cn);
}

insert notes;

for (ContentNote cn : notes) {
    ContentDocumentLink cl = new ContentDocumentLink(ContentDocumentId = cn.Id, LinkedEntityId = 'SomeAccountId', ShareType = 'I');
    l.add(cl);
}

insert l;
```

Further runs of this snippet failed with a the following error:

> Note can't be saved

After this, no user in the org is able to add any ContentNotes from the UI or Apex (UI displays:

> Note contains characters that can't be saved

even if note says `test`), even the Unit Tests fail.

I tried switching to a different IP address to no avail.
There is plenty free storage and data storage.

I have deleted the 500 notes i added, but i am still unable to add more `ContentNote` objects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get this error message when you have hit the limit. Salesforce allows limited number of content version that can be added to org in every 24 hours.

```
Environment Type    Default Maximum
Production          200,000 500,000
Sandbox             36,000  500,000
Developer Edition   2,500   2,500
Trial Environments  2,500   2,500
```

You can raise a case with Salesforce to increase it.

Read more here:- [Increase the Maximum number of 'Content Versions' published per day](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334861&type=1)